# how to store a value returned from a sql query in a variable in batch programming?

Tags: windows, sql-server-2005, scripting, command-prompt

how to store a value returned from a sql query in a variable in batch programming ?

i can invoke sqlserver queries from my cmd prompt using sqlcmd server name then the qwery

this is query statement i m going to use

SELECT
        CASE 
           WHEN DATEDIFF(minute, record_timestamp, GETDATE()) < 10 THEN 1 
           ELSE 0 
    END

how to store the value returned

i tried using set variablename but it save the statement rather than the return value ..

and if i save this in a variable what type of variable it will can i compare it with numeric values in if condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use the `cmd.exe`'s [for loop.](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/for.php) eg

```
for /F "tokens= delims=" %%a in ('sqlcmd....') do(
 set returned=%%a
)
```

`tokens` and `delims` are up to you to define.

Comment: the value returned by the query is a single value so how to use the for loop can u kindly explain more